# Different Trace Id while using Feign client in Distributed Tracing

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, spring-micrometer, distributed-tracing

I implementing Distributed tracing in microservices. I'm using feign client for inter service communication and using micrometer for tracing. But I'm getting different trace id when I call Service B from Service A using feign Client. I read a lot of articles regarding this issue, but didn't find any solution. Could anyone please help me in this? I'm using spring boot 3.0.0-Snapshot.

I expect someone will help me in this problem so I can move forward with my work, I'm stuck due to this issue.

Comment: Updated spring boot to 3.0.1 stable version it's working now..